# How Many Grenades Can a Ysoki put in their Cheeks?

Tags: starfinder

I play a ysoki technomancer with Grenade Proficiency. A few times, I've gotten away with a grenade or two stuffed in my cheeks, but the question came up of how many grenades could potentially go in there if we really wanted to commit some shenanigans (Most of them involve Raise Dead and Quick Draw).

We've established in the rules that grenades are **Bulk L.**

With that in mind, **How many grenades could a Ysoki without any modifications to their cheeks put in their cheeks before they drop them according to the rules as written?**

Note, This may be similar to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/can-i-put-my-drone-into-my-cheek-pouches) about a drone going into a Ysoki's cheek

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Up to 19 grenades

> Ysoki can store up to 1 cubic foot of items weighing up to 1 bulk in total in their cheek pouches [...]
> [Ysoki - Cheek Pouches, *Starfinder SRD*](http://www.starfindersrd.com/races/ysoki/#Cheek_Pouches)
>
> Every 10 items that have light bulk count as 1 bulk, and fractions don’t count—so 10 items with light bulk have a total of 1 bulk, and 19 such items also have a total of 1 bulk.
> [Carrying Capacity - Item Bulk, *Starfinder SRD*](http://www.starfindersrd.com/equipment/#Item_Bulk)

A grenade has a bulk of L, so 19 of them would have a bulk of 1.

There is no description of the volume or shape of a [grenade in the SRD](https://www.starfindersrd.com/equipment/weapons/#Grenades), so the amount that can fit within 1 cubic foot is undefined and left to interpretation.

Comment: I'd have to rule against that.  It might be RAW but it can't be RAI.  If you think that a Ysoki is a small humanoid and that grenades are about the size of a baseball, 5 per cheek seems reasonable.  9-10 per cheek stretches reality (and cheeks) a bit too far.

Comment: @ShadoCat To be fair, OP specifically asks for a Rules As Written reading...

Comment: Cheek pouches have a maximum of 1 cubic foot or 1 bulk. 19 grenades would  be 1 bulk according to RAW, but it seems like the would be bigger than a cubic foot.

Comment: I did some maths based on optimal sphere packing, assuming each pouch is a sphere that fits 0.5 ft^3. If a grenade is smaller than 4.172" in diameter, the bulk sets the limit. Otherwise, the volume is the limiting factor. At 4.172" in diameter, 10 grenades will fit in a 0.5 ft^3 sphere. If this is a reasonable size for a grenade is up to the DM - it's certainly not unreasonable.

Comment: @pipe Even though your calculation aren't RAW, I think this comment deserves to be written as an answer, or in addition to the existing answer!

Answer (score 7):

The rule: 
http://www.starfindersrd.com/races/ysoki/#Cheek_Pouches

In essence this gives your mausbiber a cubic foot storage capacity and an overall mass of 1 bulk (= 10 Bulk L grenades) to carry around.
Still. Considering the physiognomic features of Ysoki...  a cubic foot is like two soccer balls dangling off your face when filled. Discuss custom made antimatter grenades with your game master. As an afterthought... don't get into a brawl while trying to hold that many grenades in your pouches.

Comment: I don't think anyone even WANTS to start a brawl if you're chewing on 10 grenades.

Comment: The demise of the best planned efforts in your own role playing experience is always the same: your party members ;-)

Comment: You might as well have "Poor Impulse Control" tatooed on your forehead.

Comment: IDK. Grenade cheeks might be a terribly awesome backup plan. Only PC's have Resolve...